# Custom error page not shown in Jetty

Tags: jsp, exception, jetty, custom-error-pages, jetty-9

I'd like to show Exception at JSP parsing and running.

But not working. What do I wrong ?

I know using errorPage on page directive is one of solution to solve my problem. But I would not like to edit all files.

I edited web.xml like this.

**web.xml**

```
 <error-page>
   <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
   <location>/exception.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

My exception.jsp is here.

**exception.jsp**

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=SHIFT_JIS" pageEncoding="SHIFT_JIS" %>
<h1>
  <%= exception %>
</h1>
<pre>
  <% exception.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(out)); %>
</pre>
```

Exception occured jsp is here.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=SJIS" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <% String a = null; a.toString(); %> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**ENV**

Servlet Engine
3.1

JSP Engine
2.3

Application Server
jetty/9.2.15.v20160210

**Exception from jetty log**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 6

3: <html>
4:   <head></head>
5:   <body>
6:     <% String a = null; a.toString(); %>
7:   </body>
8: </html>


Stacktrace:
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
[...] 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:572)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        ... 63 more
```

Comment: what do you mean by *not working*? any error?

Comment: what is the output you are getting? still show the NullPointerException?

Comment: I got NullPointerException on jetty log. Page contents is empty.(not error)

Comment: Are you testing with IE? There used to be an option enabled by default to hide custom error pages.

Comment: I am using chrome.

Comment: Did you restart your server after making changes to web.xml file?

Comment: @rickz yes I restarted jetty.

Comment: I tested your code in Tomcat and it works there. I don't use Jetty, sorry.

Comment: @rickz thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you implying that errorPage directive works for you? If so, then most likely your web.xml is somehow ignored. Bad location or bad build?

Comment: @BalusC yes, when I use errorPage directive, it works. I'll make sure my web.xml. But <error-page> with <error-code> is working.

Comment: I am so sorry everyone!! Our framework is catching Exception during calling RequestDispatcher#forward(). I removed catch block , then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I once used this kind of error handling. But I am not sure if you can use an *.jsp page as error-page location. Doesn't it have to be a Servlet?

```
<!-- servlet definition -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ErrorHandler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<error-page>
   <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type >
   <location>/ErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: JSP's, once compiled, are servlets.  Just reference the servlet path in your `<location>/path/to/error.jsp</location>`.   You can also have a formal `ErrorServlet` that just uses the `RequestDispatcher` to foward the error to your JSP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for now , I'm looking for using jsp way.